# Intersection of emptyset with its complement is emptyset.

Tags: elementary-set-theory

$\emptyset\cap\bar\emptyset=\emptyset$

To prove it I want to show $\emptyset\cap\bar\emptyset\subseteq\emptyset$ and $\emptyset\subseteq\emptyset\cap\bar\emptyset$

I assume there exists an universal set U such that $\bar\emptyset=U$

First:

$\emptyset\cap\bar\emptyset\subseteq\emptyset$

Let assume $x\in \emptyset\cap\bar\emptyset$ so $x\in \emptyset$ and $x\in U=\bar\emptyset$ but since $x\in\emptyset$ is trivially false. Any implication $0\Rightarrow Q$ is trivially true. Therefore $x\in \emptyset\cap\bar\emptyset$ implies $x\in \emptyset$

And with the same logic I can show $\emptyset\subseteq\emptyset\cap\bar\emptyset$.

The emptyset is confusing me, Is it a proper way to prove the statement?

Comment: How about proving that $\emptyset\cap A=\emptyset$ for **any** set $A$?

Comment: The empty set is contained in any other set and $A\cap B\subseteq A$ for all sets $A,B$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are afraid of the empty set, start by proving that, for every subset $X$ of $U$, $X \cap \overline{X} = \emptyset$. This is easy, since by definition, $x \in \overline{X}$ if and only if $x \notin X$. Now just apply this result with $X = \emptyset$.